# RegOpenKeyExA Keeps Returning Invalid Paramater

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the `winapi (0.2.8)` and `advapi32 (0.2.0)` crates to edit registry relating to mouse acceleration. Every time I call `advapi32::RegOpenKeyExA` the program crashes and the result value is set to `INVALID_PARAMETER (87)`. The offending code is:

```
fn switch_acceleration(values: HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    let mouse: LPCSTR = CString::new("Control Panel\\Mouse").unwrap().as_ptr();

    unsafe {
        let hkey: *mut HKEY = ptr::null_mut();
        let reg_open_result = advapi32::RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, mouse, 0 as u32, winnt::KEY_WRITE | winnt::KEY_WOW64_64KEY, hkey);
        println!("{}", reg_open_result);

        for (key, value) in &values {
            let setting = CString::new(*key).unwrap().as_ptr();
            let new_val = CString::new(*value).unwrap().as_ptr() as *const u8;
            advapi32::RegSetValueExA(*hkey, setting, 0, winnt::REG_SZ, new_val, (size_of_val(&new_val) as u32));
        }

        advapi32::RegCloseKey(*hkey);            
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the samDesired option by removing `KEY_WOW_64` and/or replacing `KEY_WRITE` with `KEY_ACCESS_ALL` and I have tried replacing the registry key to open to something else however I always get the same error code no matter what I try. Which one of the arguments is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The underlying `CString` is being deallocated because there is no reference to it. `as_ptr` returns a raw pointer, there is no information of lifetime in raw pointer, so Rust thinks that is ok to deallocate the string. The solution is to name the string before using `as_ptr` (also inside the loop):

   ```
   let m = CString::new("Control Panel\\Mouse").unwrap();
   let mouse: LPCSTR = m.as_ptr();
   ```

Please read the updated docs for [`CString::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1642) RFC that tries to address this issue.

2. You are passing a null pointer (`href`) as an out parameter. You have to change the declaration of `hkey` to

   ```
   let mut hkey: HKEY = 0;
   ```

as use `&mut hkey as *mut HKEY` in `advapi32::RegOpenKeyExA` call.

Comment: *it seems weird to pass a null pointer as a out parameter* — this is true, but sometimes you pass a *reference* to a null pointer as a parameter. Then the function can allocate and return the pointer that way.